# detecting key (capslock) in a textbox

Tags: jquery

When I am typing in the textboxcontrol, can I detect if capslock is on and inform the user?

Answer (score 1):

It seem that you can detect capslock in Javascript.

For instance, see this article, which gives some code to do that : [JavaScript: Detecting Caps lock](http://blog.dougalmatthews.com/2008/07/javascript-detecting-caps-lock/)

Using this code with jQuery should be possible, I guess ; though you'll have to deal with its integration...

*(edit)* And here is some jQuery plugin that might do the trick : http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.caps.js.txt

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Artelius mentioned plugin there is also [**capslockstate**](https://github.com/nosilleg/capslockstate-jquery-plugin) plugin which has some fixes not in the above plugins.  Noticeably it detects a state change if you press the Caps Lock key itself; it doesn't lose track of the state if you type a non-alpha character; isn't limited to English keyboards; separates the act of knowing the Caps Lock state from any presentation.